# ctrl-e to switch between two files in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Most people use alt+TAB to switch between applications on their desktop.

This question is about switching between two windows in Visual Studio Code.

I am used to use ctrl-e to switch between two files in PyCharm and Chrome (via plugin [Quick Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb)).

Now I would like to do the same in vs-code.

The short cut ctrl-e opens the change file dialog. But if I hint "enter", I stay in the same file. I would have to use the down-arrow key to change the file.

Since I can blindly switch between two files in PyCharm and Chrome with ctrl-e ENTER, I would like to do the same in vs-code. How can I configure it this way?

Comment: Ctrl-tab? Or does it have to be ctrl-e?

Comment: you can change any keybinding to any other key combo, see the doc

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes, I want to use ctrl-e since I already use it in Chrome and PyCharm. ctrl-tab is not a solution.

Comment: When you say "switch between two files" do you mean go back and forth between the last two most recently used files or something else?

Comment: @Mark I added this to the question "Most people use alt+TAB to switch between applications on their desktop.

This question is about switching between two windows in Visual Studio Code."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your [keybindings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings):

File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. "Open Keyboard Shortcuts" (top right).

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+tab",
    "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup"
  },
```

See this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6923

Comment: `workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup` is a bit faster than I am used to it. As soon as I release the ctrl key it switches to the file. But overall it solves my question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I found `workbench.action.showAllEditorsByMostRecentlyUsed` to be the most like JetBrains Rider / Intellij although a extra **'Down' keystroke is needed** afterwards. It shows the most-recently-used editors and does not disappear when I release the shortcut chord.

Steps:

1. File | Preferences | Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Paste `workbench.action.showAllEditorsByMostRecentlyUsed` in the search at top
3. Replace the existing binding with `Ctrl+e`
4. Remove other `Ctrl+e` bindings if necessary